# Parsing data from an output file and creating a text file. Then creating a CSV file with the text file to create a table in the CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I'm having trouble with a code where I would like to parse data from output files and put them into a text file. I am having to extract values form an output file and create a txt file where I have the 1st column titled as weight going from 0.1 to 1 and then I have 6 more columns with the tiles being length where each title will be [0,40,80,160,250,300]. Under each of those 6 columns I have values that correspond to the weight and length say this value a constant(c). For example

```
  weight;length at 0;length at 40
  0.1;c;c
  0.2;c;c
  0.3;c;c
  0.4;c;c
  0.5;c;c
```

and so on. Each column is separated by a semi-colon. After the text file has been created, I would like to take the text file to create a CSV file to make the data more neat.

The first code creates input files. These are just input files so they will not have a 'c' value, but lets just say each one is an output file and has a 'c' value. The second code below does not work, I was supposed to extract values from output files and create a text file like above. Then after that since data is not neat, I would like to create a CSV file to make the data more neat like a table format. If anyone could help, I would deeply appreciate it so much

```
  ---This is the code that creates the input files just to add insight---

  lengths = [0,20,40,80,160,250,300]

  for l in lengths:
      Weight = 0.1
      for i in range (10):
          input = 'weight_' +str(Weight)+ '_length_' +str(l)+ '_' 
          file = open(input + '.txt','w')

          file.write('weight of box ' +str(Weight)+ '\n')
          file.write('length of box ' +str(l)+ '\n')
          file.close()

          Weight = round(Weight + 0.1, 1)
      lengths = 1      



  ------------The code actually starts here-------------

  import csv
  import itertools

  length = [0,40,80,160,250,300]

  for l in length:
      for j in range(10):
          file = open('weight_' +str(j) + '_length_' +str(l)+ '_.out','r')        
          file_lines = file.readlines()
          for line in file_lines:
              if 'constant =' in line:
              const_loc = line.index('constant =')
              C = float(line[const_loc + 10:const_loc + 17])
          output = open('extracted.txt', 'a')
          output.writelines(str(C))
          output.writelines(str())
          output.close()


  with open('extracted.txt', 'r') as in_file:
      stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
      lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
      grouped = itertools.izip(*[lines] * 3)
      with open('extracted.csv', 'w') as out_file:
          writer = csv.writer(out_file)
          writer.writerow(('title', 'intro', 'tagline'))
          writer.writerows(grouped)
```

Comment: I have couple of questions regarding your code. Where is K_loc defined? Also, as the files are created with floating point weights, the read code should also open the files with floating point values after 'weight_' in the file names. What is constant_loc and when should it be written to the file?

Comment: Please re-phrase your requirement. First part of your code creates a file on each run with 2 lines inside that does not match with your description.